# What is the algebraic structure of all the quadtrees under these operations?

Tags: set-partition, boolean-ring

I was implementing a [quadtree](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree#:%7E:text=Un%20quadtree%20ou%20arbre%20quaternaire,subdivisant%20r%C3%A9cursivement%20en%20quatre%20n%C5%93uds.) in a programming language, and I realized I could define operations such as negation $\bar{x}$, reunion $a\cup b$ and intersection $a \cap b$ on these objects.

These operations have all the propreties of a boolean algebra, but the number of elements is not 2, in fact the set of all elements is not finite.

I think this is equivalent to this situation: you have shapes on the plane with an inside, an ouside and a border. I can take the negation of a shape (the inside became the outside), the intersection of 2 shapes and the reunion of 2 shapes.

To what algebric structure does the set of all possibles shapes under this 3 laws correspond to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an algebraic structure also named "Boolean Algebra" which can be defined as a complemented distributive bounded lattice [(See the definition here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Definition). The "Boolean Algebra" as engineers, programmers, etc. call it (the one with 2 elements) is a special case (indeed a very important one, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)#Examples)) of this "Boolean Algebra" algebraic structure.

Note: In the definition linked above, there are two special elements of $A$ called $0$ and $1$. It is important, then, to emphasize in the definition that **$A$ may contain more than just $0$ and $1$!** These 2 special elements are just specified in the definition because they are used the axiom of complements $a\wedge\neg a=0$ and $a\vee\neg a=1$. In the shape analogy, $0$ and $1$ correspond to the "empty" shape, and the "whole plane" shape, respectively.

Comment: In the definition of the boolean algebra of the wiki page, they say " A Boolean algebra is a six-tuple consisting of a set A, equipped with two binary operations  [...] and **two elements 0 and 1**". Is this definition correct or can it have more?

Comment: It is correct. The two elements $0$ and $1$ are *specific* elements in the set $A$, and $A$ can have more than just the $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Ok, I see! In my example, 1 would be the entire plane and 0 the empty shape. The inversion of one give me the other. I did not realize I have these special elements ...

Comment: Could you edit your answer to make that clearer?

Comment: @rambi done! I am not sure if my edits made things clearer...